# Is there ever need for private static `fields` in android activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity, static-members, android-lifecycle

Is it ever necessary to have private static fields inside an android activity? If yes, does it matter by types of activities? such as main activity, fragments, etc.

Answer (score 1):

They're rarely (if ever) *necessary*, but sometimes private static fields are useful. For example, they can be used to define constants that are only used within an single `Activity`, such as result codes for `startActivityForResult` or constant string keys for storing data in `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: I use `final` to define constants. What value does using `static` add in the instances you site?

Comment: I typically use `final` as well. If you're defining the constants in classes that are instantiated many times, making them `static` avoids the memory (and GC) overhead of having a copy of the constants in each instance.

Comment: It's worth noting that some JVM implementations might automatically do the type of memory optimization that I mentioned for primitive types, but using `static` for heavier objects can facilitate a simple [flyweight pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use them. They would be good for using within an Anonymous inner class, or inner class for that matter. It's one way to can pass data between the inner class and outer class. However, to do this, you would also need to declare it as `final`.

Fragments can be, and usually are, created as inner classes within Activities, so if you were doing something within the fragment and needed to pass that value back to the Activity, you would use a static field. Making it private, unless there is a reason to make it public, is good coding procedure.

Comment: As far as I know (anonymous) inner classes have access to the instance variable of the outer class. There's no need for sharing a static field between them.

Comment: Not the static, but they do need `final`

Comment: yeah, as @NobuGames says, I don't see the need for static in the instances you present.